# Quick action in standard salesforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

We have an action of type ‘Custom Visualforce’ on a custom object called Trip.
This action is added as a quick action in to the ‘Quick Actions in the Salesforce Classic Publisher’ menu in the page layout of the trip object.

The action is a simple visualforce page with firstname and lastname columns which when entered creates an account and also creates a related record for trip member object (after clicking the create member button). 
The objective of this VF page was a way for users to quickly create an account if it did not exist and doing it from the quick action on the page would save some time.
There is a master detail relationship between trip and trip member and the trip members appear as a  related list in the trip page layout.

Code is very similar to this.
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=custom_actions_vf_pages_for_object_actions.htm&langu_3

The issue is we the related list does not get refreshed once an account has been created using the quick action , I know this is not possible with standard sf and we may have to go for a VF page. Issue is users have to refresh the page to see if the trip member has been added to the page.

But I was also wondering if there was a better way of implementing this whole thing.

Any suggestion is much appreciated

Comment: This will refresh the entire page `Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({ name: "publisher.close", payload: {refresh:"true"}});` which should refresh the related lists. https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/visualforce_mobile_salesforce1/visualforce_mobile_salesforce1_actions_object

Comment: Thanks @Eric , I have checked the trailhead module and the page refresh works only for Salesforce1 actions and not for ‘Quick Actions in the Salesforce Classic Publisher’. The page just stays as is after adding the line you suggested. Is there any other way?

Comment: Can;t you just create a page reference method to redirect to the Object detail view?

Comment: @Eric thanks, I tried it just now, the issue with that is the page redirects in that small feed window and not the main page.